# Python re.sub not working with colorama and re.compile

Tags: python, regex, colors

I have the following program which searches for a string in lines in a certain location and then outputs the search matches. I want to be able to choose whether to ignore case in the search and highlight the search string in the output line.

```
import re, os, glob  
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style  
init(autoreset=True)

path = "c:\\temp2"  
os.chdir(path) 

def get_str(msg):
    myinput = input(msg)
    while True:
        if not bool(myinput):
            myinput = input('No Input..\nDo it again\n-->')
            continue
        else:
            return myinput

ext = get_str('Search the files with the following extension...')
find = get_str('Search string...')
case = get_str('    Ignore case of search string? (y/n)...')   
print()

if case == "y" or case == "Y":
    find = re.compile(find, re.I) 
else:
    find = find

files_to_search = glob.glob('*.' + ext)

for f in files_to_search:
    input_file = os.path.join(path, f)
    with open(input_file) as fi:
        file_list = fi.read().splitlines() 
        for line in file_list:
            if re.search(find, line):  
                line = re.sub(find, Fore.YELLOW + find + Fore.RESET, line)
                print(f, "--", line)
```

The program works if I select "n" for case. If I select "y" I get this error when the program is run:

```
Search the files with the following extension...txt  
Search string...this  
    Ignore case of search string? (y/n)...y  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\7. apps\eclipse\1. workspace\learning\scratch\scratchy.py", line 36, in <module>
    line = re.sub(find, Fore.YELLOW + find + Fore.RESET, line)  
TypeError: Can't convert '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object to str implicitly
```

How can I make this work for the "yes" case?

Comment: You're redefining your variable `find` to a regex when the answer for case-insensitivity is yes. See your if-else case there: `find - re.compile...` versuse `find = find`. While a really superfluous else statement, it does keep `find` a string that was put in earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with the string concatenation you're doing in your `re.sub` call. The expression `Fore.YELLOW + find + Fore.RESET` isn't valid if `find` is a compiled regular expression object instead of a string.

To fix this, I suggest using a different variable name for the regular expression pattern than you use for the original string:

```
if case == "y" or case == "Y":
    pattern = re.compile(find, re.I)
else:
    pattern = find
```

Then pass `pattern` as the first argument to `re.sub`. `find` will remain a string in all cases, so it will work in expression in the second argument:

```
line = re.sub(pattern, Fore.YELLOW + find + Fore.RESET, line)
```

Comment: Thats just about done it. Also have to change the search to 'if re.search(pat, line):'